# How to check that a ruby hash excludes certain keys?

Tags: ruby, rspec

In rspec, suppose I have a hash `myHash`

How can I check that myHash doesn't have the following keys: "A", "B", "C"?

The following is valid ruby but does the opposite of what I want:

```
myHash.should include(:A, :B, :C)
```

Why isn't there a `should exclude`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`should_not include`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher#hash-usage)

```
myHash.should_not include(:A, :B, :C)
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Rspec 3.0](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher), we should use :

```
expect(my_hash).not_to include(:A, :B, :C)
```

Comment: In case anybody is curious, as I was - the negated `include` matcher *does* (as advertised here) work differently than the logical opposite of the include matcher, so this does what you would want/expect ;)  It will check to make sure the given hash/array doesn't include *any* of the given arguments, not just that it doesn't include *all* of them (which would be the logical opposite of the include matcher).